Auto-breakdown to separate items when copy from Excel to a Workshop filter
I am hoping to replicate the copy paste function in Contour to a Workshop application that I am building.
As you know, when you copy a list of items (e.g. from Excel) into a Contour's filter, it will automatically break them down to separate items (screenshot). I can't seem to do this in a Workshop application's filter.

The only way that I can think of is use a function backed text area but haven't managed to do that.

Indeed, using a Function is the right move here. You will essentially parse the string and perform the operation(s) you need on it.
Example of function (untested, but should give you a high level pointer):
@Function()
function parseExcelString(excelString: string) : string[] {
  // Split the string by newlines and tabs to separate all items
  const items = excelString.trim().split(/[\n\t]/);

  return items;
}

Steps at high level:

Create a code repository
Select "Functions" > "Typescript"
Write the above function (you will need to uncomment the import present by default)
Commit (top right button) and tag (top right button)
Wait for the function to be published

And in workshop:

Add the text input widget
Create a variable (let's call it parsed_strings_array) that is a "function execution" and that outputs a string array

Select your function published above ("parseExcelString")

You now have a variable with an array of the different values populated from what was copy-pasted by the user !
You can now use this string array variable to filter your Object set variable by selecting Filter ... On a property ... (x)


hi @zettaP, so let say I already had the string arrays that are generated from the text input going through the function, how can I actually wire this up as a filter list to be used by my main object table? It seems like it only accepts 'Filter List - Filter Output' from an actual filter, not from a single variable?

Completed my answer :)
